# fetch() POST requests with Express: unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: javascript, express, post, fetch

I've been trying to practice with some HTTP requests, and specifically I want to send a POST request, with data taken from an  field, and sent via fetch() to a url on my localhost thats set up with express. From there i want to somehow get the response back and have that be displayed on my HTML doc.

However, I've ran into a real head scratcher when it comes to getting response.json() to be anything other than undefined.

here's my frontend script:

```
const url = "/result";

const inputField = document.querySelector("#write");
const submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit");
const responseField = document.querySelector("#text-goes-here");

const postText = async () => {
  const text = inputField.value;
  const data = JSON.stringify({ destination: text });

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "POST",
      body: data,
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
      },
    });

    if (response.ok === true) {
      const jsonResponse = await response.json();
      responseField.innerHTML = jsonResponse;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const displayText = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  while (responseField.firstChild) {
    responseField.removeChild(responseField.firstChild);
  }

  postText();
};

submitButton.addEventListener("click", displayText);
```

and my server script:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const read = require('fs');
const router = express.Router();
const app = express();

const port = 3000;


app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("public/index.html");
})

router.post("/result", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send();
});

app.use("/", router);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at port: ${port}`)
});
```

I did some digging in the dev console and found that (response.ok) is in fact "true", yet it errors out into the catch statement saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at postText (script.js:23)"

which is this line exactly:

```
const jsonResponse = await response.json();
```

can anyone shed any light on what i'm doing wrong here? I'm at a loss at this point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that you're trying to parse something that is not a valid JSON object.

```
"SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at postText (script.js:23)"
```

Which is true, because the response you're sending back to the frontend is not a JSON.

```
router.post("/result", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    // The response is not a valid JSON object
    res.send();
});
```

You can change `res.send()` to `res.json()` and give it a valid object.

```
res.json({ name:"John", age:30, car:null })
```